# Design: Displaying different button for different variable (ie. user,status)

Tags: java, spring, design-patterns, spring-mvc

Problem statement:

Each report has multiple task.
The report task are display in a table
Each Task has different options(A, B, D, E, X)
The options are shown as hyperlink in a table column

For different roles and task status, the options shown will be different.

ie (status s1 and role r1) will show option A and B

May I know how should I design it to allow the view to display different option each time?

My initiate design:

Having a hashmap to store this options vs keys and populate the TaskModel with the options

May I know if there is a better solution and what kind of design pattern can I use?

Comment: Have you tried spring security Access Control Lists (ACL)? http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/domain-acls.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create a wrapper class for the `ReportTask` instances which would handle the context sensitive option handling.

The wrapper could look something like:

```
class StatusRoleContextReportTaskWrapper {
    private ReportTask;

    public StatusRoleContextReportTaskWrapper(ReportTask task) { ... }

    public Option[] getOptions() { /* return options based on role and status */ }

    public static StatusRoleContextReportTaskWrapper[] getWrapped(ReportTask[] tasks) {
        /* wrap tasks ... */
        return wrappedTasks;
    }
}
```

Here's a sample controller method.

```
public String reportTaskList(ModelMap model) {
    ReportTask[] tasks = reportTaskService.getSome();
    model.add("reportTasks", StatusRoleContextReportTaskWrapper.getWrapped(tasks));

    return "taskListView";
}
```

Comment: can't +1 you for effort... any web document on this way of managing?

Comment: It's a simple [adapter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) to change the behavior of the original `ReportTask` instance. It's a general concept and not exclusive to the web in any way.